# Docker pull using a high speed network

Tags: docker

We have a private Docker registry set up with in our data center.

It has a Data center IP with an internal DNS name(part of 10gig network) as well as a private IP(sub domain) which is part of a 100gig network. our kubernetes cluster is part of the same 100gig network.

Am trying to see if I can do a docker pull using the 100gig network from our k8s cluster. I am not sure my docker pull commands are using 10gig network vs 100gig.

Is there a way to either force or identify which network its using?

Comment: This is a simple routing issue: Just use an address for your registry that is only accessible via the high speed interface.

Comment: Registry has a DNS name which resolves to only 10 gig address. Docker pull would be using DNS name like <DNS Name>/REPO:TAG. I have tried appending the /etc/hosts file <DNS Name> to point to the high speed IP address but there is no way to see the traffic how its resolving. Mac Daemon debug gives you the details, but am not seeing any details on our RHEL host message logs.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to give your registry an alternate dns name that resolves to the ip address of the 100gig interface. You should see logs on the registry side that show the address from which the client is connecting (or just use `tcpdump` for this).